# ¿Se puede abrir WhatsApp desde una WebView?

Tags: html, webview-android

tengo un error y no puedo resolverlo, si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecere mucho. 
Hice una aplicacion de WebView  en android, el cual dirige a un sitio subido en un host gratuito, pero en dicha pagina yo cree links para abrir WHatsapp(utilizando el api), de abrir la aplicacion de correo y la de marcar, en la PC me cargan pero al abrirlos en la aplicación me dice que la pagina no esta disponible, ¿tendra algo que ver que es una webview y no respeta esos links?

Comment: Hola Raul Simon, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta**, saludos!

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: yo tengo exactamente el mismo problema y aún no puedo encontrar solución, vos ya pudiste? En el caso de que sea yo quien encuentre primero la respuesta sin falta estaré compartiendola. Saludos !!

Comment: tengo exactamente el mismo problema y he buscado y no encuentro nada relacionado, es el primer foro que veo que tiene una pregunta similar o exactamente igual a lo que me esta pasando quiero saber si ya han podido solucionarlo

Comment: No soy experto en el tema, pero en mi caso no sé si en el de ustedes, agregaron el código de webClients, bueno yo lo agregue porq al iniciar otro URL está se salía de la app y abría era el navegador, nosotros al agregar esa línea lo que hicimos fue q no usará servicios externos a la aplicación, entonces considero y creo q es por esa razón, ya q el WhatsApp móvil no se inicia desde un navegador sino de la propia app y al dirigirse al URL de WhatsApp pues no inicia porq no existe un inicio de sesión en el navegador del dispositivo móvil sino desde la app